# Caulking around top edge of counters

Tags: kitchen-counters

We had a new house built, within a month of taking ownership the caulking started cracking and the countertops look like they’re pulling away from the wall, as much as 3/8th of an inch! They are sinking from the end pieces attached to the wall.  This looks horrible, I’m ashamed to have anyone come over.  I can’t get anyone from TK constructors to return my call.  Any idea what’s wrong??

Comment: What kind of countertops? Pictures?

Comment: Sounds like the floor may be sinking, which may be a sign of a serious structural issue. Picture would help to clarify

Comment: Take pictures, even if just for your own records, and write a letter.  Most places have have a builders association and/or a better business.  Send them copies of your letter and pictures, letting the builder of your house know.  Your builder should have given you a warranty for the house.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg, don't freak this lady out about structural failure. I know the building trade is suffering terribly from shoddy workmanship, but building inspectors are SUPPOSED to inspect building as they are built to prevent structural failures. If the OP could show some pictures, some close up and a few taken at a distance to show context, and one at an inside corner of the countertop if applicable, This all might amount to no more than a LOT of shrinkage, since builders slap houses up so fast, even during wet weather.

Comment: Are the countertops pulling away from the wall horizontally, or vertically (ie, countertop sinking down)? Are the feet under kitchen cabinets well mounted and solid, or shoddy? Did they mount all the feet?  Is the problem occurring where the countertop is supported by cabinets, or over a dishwasher where it is not supported? If you grab the countertop and push/pull, does it move?

Comment: Can you post pictures? One useful thing to do would be to check of the floor is horizontal and flat, for example with a 2-3 meters straight edge and a bubble level.